# Como trabalhar com visibility do CSS?

Tags: css

Saudação,

O que estou precisando fazer é fazer uma imagem ficar invisível quando a resolução de tela atingir 576px, porém não estou tendo sucesso, estou fazendo assim;

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-2 topo_branco animated  fadeInDown">
     <img src="assets/img/seta.JPG" height="250" >
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topo_branco{
  visibility: visible;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 576px){

      .topo_branco{
        visibility: hidden;
      }

}
```

**O que pode está havendo de errado?**

Comment: Nada, seu código funciona perfeitamente: http://output.jsbin.com/rimulayacu. Por quê não elabora um [mcve] demonstrando o problema?

Comment: monte um código para que possamos validar exatamente. Criei um fiddle e "oculta" a div e a imagem, o que exatamente não está funcionando? http://jsfiddle.net/rjq402vL/

Comment: Quando a resolução chega aos 576px era para a imagem ficar invisível.

Comment: Qual browser está utilizando?

Comment: Seu problema pode ser pq vc está usando duas classes de "visibility" uma na mão no @media e a outra com o o fadeInDown do animeted.css, elas devem estar conflitando e sobrescrevendo algo assim... teste remover a classe `fadeInDown` para testar que deve resolver.

Comment: @wladyband E é exatamente isso que seu código faz. Veja que eu simplesmente copiei e colei o seu código no meu exemplo e funcionou. Então faça um [mcve] demonstrando o problema, pois há outros fatores na sua aplicação que estão influenciando e que não foram descritos na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o conceito de Mobile First.

```
.topo_branco{
   visibility: hidden;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 20px 0;
   padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px){
   .topo_branco{
      visibility: visible;
   }
}
```

Isso significa que até chegar em **575px** a imagem é invisível.
Quando atingir **576px** a imagem ficará visível.

Comment: só complementando: remover a visibilidade não tira o elemento do campo de visão de tela. Ele oculta com visibility, mas o tamanho de 200px vai continuar na sua tela. Vai ficar um vazio de 200x200. Se que sumir de fato sem deixar um rastro visível, use o display:none. Esse sim oculta do mesmo jeito, mas não deixa uma caixa invisível de 200px.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas foi o que ele pediu. Quando ele quiser que o elemento não apareça na tela aí eu modifico minha resposta.